# actionbar overflow menu items icons padding

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

[image]

Hello, I would like to know if it's possible to somehow reduce margin, that `android:icon="@drawable/ic_credit_card_black_18dp"` creates for menu item

`

```
    <menu>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
                android:title="@string/settings_profile_title">
        </item>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_cards"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_credit_card_black_18dp"
            app:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="@string/settings_cards_title">
        </item>
        <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_notifications"
                android:title="@string/settings_notifications_title">
        </item>`
```

...

Comment: please share some more info, e.g. the full xml

Comment: Don't know which info is relevant to you. It's simple menu.xml with parameter `android:icon`. You can add any icon to your overflow menu, and should see same margin effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a style on your styles.xml and set @style/AppTheme as the Activity's theme, if I'm not mistaken the default is 80dip or 50dip (might be for width, your looking for height).

Try adding this in you styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minHeight">15dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">15dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I think this works for CustomActionBarStyle, but it does not changes that icon margin LEFT or RIGHT in any way

Comment: try playing with the padding and max/minWidth, the Custom is yours, you can manipulate it as you see fit, try playing with more item params, you'll probably find what you're looking for :)